# Using Variables in Model

Tags: php, variables, model

Well, I have the following function in my Model:

```
public function get_learning_category_list() {
 $categorias = $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.title, t1.metadata, t1.meta_title, t1.description, t1.meta_description, t1.meta_spam, t1.url, t1.alt_img')
    ->from('learning_category t1')
    ->join('learning_rel_category t4', 't1.id = t4.category_id', 'left')
    ->join('learning t2', 't4.learning_id = t2.id', 'left')
    ->join('learning_rel_language t3', 't2.id = t3.learning_id', 'left')
    ->where('t3.language', $this->language)
    ->group_by('t1.id')
    ->get()->result_array();
foreach($categorias as $c){
    $total = $this->db->select('count(learning_rel_language.learning_id) as total', false)
    ->from('learning')
    ->join('learning_rel_language', 'learning.id = learning_rel_language.learning_id', 'inner')
    ->join('learning_rel_category', 'learning.id = learning_rel_category.learning_id', 'inner')
    ->where('learning_rel_category.category_id', $c['id'])
    ->where('learning_rel_language.language', $this->language)
    ->group_by('learning_rel_language.language')->get()->first_row('array');

    $metadata = json_decode($c['metadata']);
    $tt = $c['title'];
    $url = $c['url'];
    if($this->language != 'pt_br'){
        $tt = $metadata->{$this->language};
        $tt_pt_br = $c['title'];
    }

    $return[] = array('url' => $url, 'title'=>$tt, 'id'=>$c['id'], 'total'=>$total['total'], 'title_pt_br'=>$tt_pt_br);

}

return $return; //$categorias;
}
```

giving a `print_r($this->learn->get_learning_category_list());` I results in this value :

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Title [id] => 2 [total] => 6 [title_pt_br] => )`

Beauty ? But I need to use ( the same Model ) these values ​​, url and title etc. How can I do this?

Being more specific , I need to use here:

`$category_format = (here title).'-cmdo-'.(here id);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the array retrieved from the Model, here is what you can do:

```
$categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
foreach($categorias as $cat){
    $category_format = $cat['title'].'-cmdo-'.$cat['id'];
}
```

if you want objects, change this line:

```
$return[] = array('url' => $url, 'title'=>$tt, 'id'=>$c['id'], 'total'=>$total['total'], 'title_pt_br'=>$tt_pt_br);
```

By this:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->url = $url;
$object->title = $tt;
$object->id = $c['id'];
$object->total = $total['total'];
$object->title_pt_br = $tt_pt_br;
$return[] = $object;
```

Comment: it worked! but the result comes in Array, how can I make it an object?

Comment: See my edit, and don't forget to set the answer as correct :)